# copying the visual studio settings for one project to another

Tags: visual-studio-2010, settings

I have a visual studio 2010 project done in VB.net and i have around 45 variables in the application settings. The one you set in the properties.settings. Now i m having a similar project and i wanna copy the settings variables to this project. Not sure how to proceed with this.

what i did is tried to copy the auto generated code for the settings into that project and it didnt work out well. I am not even sure how to google this out and tried the following.

1. copying application settings from one project to another in visual studio
2. moving application settings between visual studio projects

Both of this didnt get what i wanted and am actually out of clue on what to search for this.

So is there a way to directly copy the settings from one project to another project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All I did was grab the physical Settings.Designer.vb and Settings.settings files found in the "My Project" folder of your applicaton (assuming it's a windows App and not web) and copied/replaced the existing settings files in the new project.
Did a rebuild of new project and errors kicked back but that was just the desinger code referencing the old project name. Corrected by replacing the old project name with the new one and voila, worked.

HTH

Dave